# Is it possible to build a queue sharing group on only a coupling facility and not use db2?

Tags: db2, zos, ibm-mq

I keep reading docs that say the messages are kept in a cf and can be offloaded to smds or db2 if they are too large. This would suggest I could build out queues in a cf and offload large messages to disk and avoid db2 all together. Then other docs say the queue objects are stored in db2 and db2 is necessary. Is it possible to build a QSG without db2?

Answer (score 2):

While it is true that you can create a Queue Sharing Group (QSG) that does not **store messages** in DB2, you still need DB2 for object definitions, and thus DB2 is still a pre-requisite to creating a QSG.

So, no, it is not possible to build a QSG without DB2.

There is [an RFE](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/execute?use_case=viewRfe&CR_ID=23659) about this where you should add your vote.